# How to check if code is running inside simpletest?

Tags: testing

Here's the best I've come up with so far:

```
/**
 * Returns TRUE if our code is running via a simpletest.
 *
 * We don't check for the database prefix so that this can be used by Unit
 * Tests also.
 *
 * We could set a variable in the test setUp method and check that variable,
 * but then some dummy could misuse that variable in code intended for
 * production.
 */
function check_is_simpletest() {
    return class_exists('DrupalTestCase', FALSE) || strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'simpletest') === 0;
}
```

Is this crazy? I'd expect it to break in the Testing UI pages of the site, but I'm only concerned with testing custom code which will not affect those pages, and I usually test via drush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Drupal 7, take a look at [drupal_valid_test_ua()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/drupal_valid_test_ua/7), it appears to return the database prefix when simpletest is running, or FALSE otherwise

It is used in **_drupal_bootstrap_database()**:

```
  // The user agent header is used to pass a database prefix in the request when
  // running tests. However, for security reasons, it is imperative that we
  // validate we ourselves made the request.
  if ($test_prefix = drupal_valid_test_ua()) {
    // Set the test run id for use in other parts of Drupal.
    $test_info = &$GLOBALS['drupal_test_info'];
    $test_info['test_run_id'] = $test_prefix;
    $test_info['in_child_site'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 4):

In Drupal 7, [drupal_http_request()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/7) use the following code to add an extra header, when tests are running.

```
  // If the database prefix is being used by SimpleTest to run the tests in a copied
  // database then set the user-agent header to the database prefix so that any
  // calls to other Drupal pages will run the SimpleTest prefixed database. The
  // user-agent is used to ensure that multiple testing sessions running at the
  // same time won't interfere with each other as they would if the database
  // prefix were stored statically in a file or database variable.
  $test_info = &$GLOBALS['drupal_test_info'];
  if (!empty($test_info['test_run_id'])) {
    $options['headers']['User-Agent'] = drupal_generate_test_ua($test_info['test_run_id']);
  }
```

In your module, similar code should work.

```
  $test_info = $GLOBALS['drupal_test_info'];
  if (!empty($test_info['test_run_id'])) {
    // Drupal is running tests.
  }
```

In Drupal 6, the following code is present in [drupal_http_request()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_http_request/6).

```
  // If the database prefix is being used by SimpleTest to run the tests in a copied
  // database then set the user-agent header to the database prefix so that any
  // calls to other Drupal pages will run the SimpleTest prefixed database. The
  // user-agent is used to ensure that multiple testing sessions running at the
  // same time won't interfere with each other as they would if the database
  // prefix were stored statically in a file or database variable.
  if (is_string($db_prefix) && preg_match("/^simpletest\d+$/", $db_prefix, $matches)) {
    $defaults['User-Agent'] = 'User-Agent: ' . $matches[0];
  }
```

The following code should work for a Drupal 6 module.

```
  global $db_prefix;

  if (is_string($db_prefix) && preg_match("/^simpletest\d+$/", $db_prefix)) {
    // Drupal is running tests.
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in Drupal 8:

```
if ( array_key_exists('simpletest.settings', $GLOBALS['conf']) ) {
  return;
}
```

I used this in hook_node_presave in a .module file, to stop the hook code being executed during testing.

Comment: `drupal_valid_test_ua()` still works as well.